# Cakephp Pagination is not working?

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I am new to cakephp, My pagination is not working..

My controller code:

```
$this->paginate = array('Favourite' =>array('limit' => '1','conditions'=>array('user_id'=>$id))); 
$cat_data = $this->paginate('Favourite');
$this->set('fav_data',$cat_data);
```

My view code:

```
<!---Code for pagination   -->
<div>
 <?php echo $this->Paginator->prev('', null, null, array('class' => 'pdisable','escape' => false)); ?>
<div class="numbers"><?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers(); ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;Pages: <?php echo $this->Paginator->counter(); ?></div>
<?php echo $this->Paginator->next('', null, null, array('class' => 'ndisable','escape' => false)); ?>
 </div>
```

It is not displaying one result based on the limit i have given.. It displays all the records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are trying to get the paginated recordset using this line in your code:

`$cat_data = $this->paginate('Favourite');`

You are actually redeclaring the paginate settings a second time, only without the limit or condition specified anymore. You need to use the `Paginator` Component class with the Paginate settings you declare beforehand.

In your code:

//here your are declaring the paginate settings one time.

`$this->paginate = array('Favourite' =>array('limit'=>'1','conditions'=>array('user_id'=>$id)));`

//Here you are re-declaring them again, only not with a limit or condition specified. This effectively overwrites the first settings declaration you made.

`$cat_data = $this->paginate('Favourite');`

`$this->set('fav_data',$cat_data);`

Change:

`$cat_data = $this->paginate('Favourite');`

To:

`$cat_data = $this->Paginator->paginate('Favourite');`

So your controller code should look like:

```
//declare settings without conditions.
$this->paginate = array(
   'limit' => 1
);

//use above settings to pull the paginated results.
//be sure to add the conditions you had in the settings before to the 2nd parameter of the `paginate()` function.
$this->set('fav_data', $this->Paginator->paginate('Favourite', array('user_id' => $id)));
```